# regex for alphanumieric string pattern with underscores and min occurannce and no max occurance - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am new to regex and trying validation in javascript/jquery using regex, appreciate any help.

The input is :

1. alphanumeric string
2. with minimum 3 underscores
3. Underscores cannot be consecutive
4. Underscores cannot just be separated by empty strings
5. The string cannot start or end with an underscore

Valid test cases:

1. `Abc_def_gh_123`
2. `Abc_def_1h_103_BA`
3. `Abc_def_1h_103_BA`

Invalid test cases

1. `___`
2. `_ _ _`
3. `Abc_d`
4. `Abc_def_ghi_de21_`
5. `Abc_def_fg`
6. `Abc_def_fg_`
7. `_Abc_def_fg`

I had tried regex in javascript

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

but it fails eg. if the string has more than 3 underscores

Comment: So Java, JavaScript or Perl?

Comment: javaacript please - I had  regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/;
Where it fails – when the string has more than 3 underscores

Comment: Can you edit your question with whatever regex you have tried till now

Comment: what about this `_ad_af_ag`?

Comment: click on edit, after the tags: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25621191/edit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This regexp should do the job:

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+_){3,}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/
```

Comment: So can we say that this answer was the first corrent one?

Answer (score 2):

```
(?=^[a-zA-Z0-9]+?_[a-zA-Z0-9]+?_[a-zA-Z0-9]+?_[a-zA-Z0-9_]*$)(?!.*?_$)(?!.*?_{2,}.*)^.*$
```

Try this.This works.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/pP3pN1/5

Comment: "_ad_af_ag" passes your regExp, while it shouldn't

Comment: `Abc_def_gh__123` also :/

Comment: @TomSarduy It is under valid test case.

Comment: @vks: The OP says *Underscores cannot be consecutive*

Comment: @vks: take your time ;) check `Abc_def_fg`

Comment: @TomSarduy one missed dot it was :( :P nonetheless my relentless effort continues.Now see

Comment: @vks if I'm correct, you can write `\S` instead of `[^\s]`

Comment: @AvinashRaj so which case is failing now

Comment: @Regent ahhhh bas miss :(

Comment: don't see the cases. See the first rule.

Answer (score 1):

```
/([a-zA-Z0-9]+_[a-zA-Z0-9]+){3,}$/mg
```

http://regex101.com/r/yQ2xS9/2

Breakdown:

`[a-zA-Z0-9]+`  Starts with any number of lowercase and uppercase letters, or numbers.

`_[a-zA-Z0-9]+` Contains an underscore followed by another sequence of lowercase/uppercase letters and numbers.

`{3,}$` Minimum of three times (three lots of underscores)

Happy coding :)